# How to make changes to directory permissions permanent?

Tags: permissions

I have a second internal hard drive installed on my desktop machine. I figured out how to change its permissions so that every user on the system has rwx on its directories. This is where I am:

```
root@erwin-Aspire-TC-605:/media/erwin# ls
2TB  CCCOMA_X64FRE_EN-US_DV9
root@erwin-Aspire-TC-605:/media/erwin#
```

So I type `chmod -R 777 2TB` and the whole thing works.

The problem is that when I reboot the system, it reverts to its original setting.

Which config file do I have to write to and what do I write to make the permission changes permanent?

Comment: This is not normal behavior for an Ubuntu system. Do any other elements of your system reset when you reboot? The use of root is also unusual when using Ubuntu. Is that a preference, or is it necessary? Exactly which release of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: What file system is the drive using?